# Jenkins 1.580.1 jdk 5 build fails

Tags: jenkins, build, java-5

I use Jenkins version 1.580.1 and when i run build of job with JDK 5 he fails and he pass in success with JDK 6, 
i run the clean install on the console with jdk5 that worked fine.
Can any one help me to know why jenkins 1.580.1 don't work with jdk5 
thanks a lot
The log Error :

```
Parsing POMs
maven-agent.jar already up to date
classworlds.jar already up to date
maven-interceptor.jar already up to date
maven2.1-interceptor.jar already up to date
[TM_ORANGE_LANGNAT_build] $ /cip/opt/jdk1.5.0_22/bin/java -Xmx1024M -XX:PermSize=128M -XX:MaxPermSize=512M -cp /cip/home/jenkins-V1/maven-agent.jar:/cip/home/jenkins-V1/classworlds.jar hudson.maven.agent.Main /cip/opt/apache-maven-2.2.1 /cip/home/jenkins-V1/slave.jar /cip/home/jenkins-V1/maven-interceptor.jar 60645 /cip/home/jenkins-V1/maven2.1-interceptor.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:124)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:260)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:56)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:195)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.RealmClassLoader.loadClassDirect(RealmClassLoader.java:195)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.DefaultClassRealm.loadClass(DefaultClassRealm.java:255)
at hudson.maven.agent.Main.main(Main.java:143)
at hudson.maven.agent.Main.main(Main.java:68)
ERROR: Failed to parse POMs
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:168)
at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:116)
at hudson.remoting.ProxyInputStream$Buffer.read(ProxyInputStream.java:110)
at hudson.remoting.ProxyInputStream$Chunk.perform(ProxyInputStream.java:132)
at hudson.remoting.ProxyInputStream$Chunk.perform(ProxyInputStream.java:119)
at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:324)
at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:68)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
at ......remote call to FRASCIPSLAVE-1(Native Method)
at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1356)
at hudson.remoting.Request.call(Request.java:171)
at hudson.remoting.ProxyInputStream._read(ProxyInputStream.java:74)
at hudson.remoting.ProxyInputStream.read(ProxyInputStream.java:80)
at hudson.remoting.RemoteInputStream.read(RemoteInputStream.java:269)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:256)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:317)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:218)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:237)
at hudson.remoting.ChannelBuilder.negotiate(ChannelBuilder.java:329)
at hudson.remoting.ChannelBuilder.build(ChannelBuilder.java:280)
at hudson.slaves.Channels.forProcess(Channels.java:114)
at hudson.maven.AbstractMavenProcessFactory.newProcess(AbstractMavenProcessFactory.java:253)
at hudson.maven.ProcessCache.get(ProcessCache.java:236)
at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.doRun(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:749)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:533)
at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1745)
at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:519)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:89)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:240)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Best regards,
Youssef

Comment: Without giving more information than "he fails", it won't be easy for anybody to help you. What specific errors do you see when building with JDK 5?

Comment: thanks Christopher for your response, i edited my question and added the log error ;)